# Mathematics Behind Coincidence of Probabilities (Magic the Gathering Example)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, optimization

In Magic the Gathering, a player must decide how many land cards to include in his or her deck.  Drawing too few at the beginning of a game is called mana screw.  Drawing too many at the beginning of a game is called mana flood.  Both make winning the game an uphill battle.  The ordinary course of action would be to add land cards to your deck if you experience mana screw more frequently, and remove land cards from your deck if you experience mana flood more frequently, in other words, equalize the frequencies of the two outcomes to the extent possible.

However, I wondered if this might be the wrong goal.  Why should it matter if the probabilities of the two bad outcomes are the same?  What really matters is minimizing the probability that either outcome obtains, that is, maximizing the probability that an acceptable number of land cards gets drawn.  I tested this in Mathematica...

[image]

As can be seen, these quantities exactly coincide.  As I change the parameters defining how many land cards constitute "too few" or "too many," the minimum of the first graph moves in lockstep with the zero of the second graph.  This lends support to the ordinary course of action.

Why does this happen mathematically?  It is not the case that *any* $f(x) + g(x)$ has extrema where $f(x) - g(x)$ has zeros.  Minimizing isn't a linear operator, so it's not clear that minimizing the sum relates to minimizing the summands.  Is there a clear reason that this happens here?  Is it an attribute of probability distributions?  The hypergeometric distribution in particular?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the helpful graph, the function you are trying to minimize looks roughly symmetrical. Say the probability of screw with x lands in $80$, $f(x)$, is about the same as the probability of flood with $70-x$ lands in $80$.

So we write the probability of a bad hand as $f(x) + f(70-x)$. Differentiating, it’s easy to see that the minimum is at $x’$ is where $x’=70/2=35$. But this is exactly where $f(x’)=f(70-x’)$.

So the rough symmetry explains this artifact.

Remark for Magic players: In the game, the relative damage of screw vs flood may be different. E.g., in Limited, one may escape from a screw with just a single good draw, but flood results in a diluted hand that may take a long time to escape from. But with other decks, the relative impact may be different and even reversed.